# What is the difference between setMany and setAll functions of Redux-ToolKit createEntityAdapter?

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit

What is the difference between `setMany` and `setAll` functions of Redux-ToolKit `createEntityAdapter`?

I have watched [docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createEntityAdapter#crud-functions), but I am still confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a subtle difference between the two. I've emphasized the significant difference below in the quoted block from the docs.

> - `setMany`: accepts an array of entities or an object in the shape of `Record<EntityId, T>`, and ***adds or replaces*** them.
> - `setAll`: accepts an array of entities or an object in the shape of `Record<EntityId, T>`, and ***replaces all existing entities*** with
>   the values in the array.

`setMany` will update existing entries ***or*** add new entries. `setAll` completely replaces all existing entries with what was passed in the array/object.